# Heuristics for the Asymmetric Traveling Salesman

Tags: algorithm, artificial-intelligence, a-star, heuristics, traveling-salesman

I am using A* in order to solve the Asymmetric Traveling Salesman problem.
My state representation has 4 variables:

1 - Visited cities (List)

2 - Unvisitied cities (List)

3 - Current City (Integer)

4 - Current Cost (Integer)

However, even tho I find many path-construction algorithms such as Nearest Neighbor, k-opt and so on, I can't find an heuristic suitable for A*, which is, a h(n) function that takes a state as input and returns an integer corresponding to that state's quality.

So my question is, are there such heuristics? Any recommendations?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The weight of the minimum spanning tree of the subgraph that contains all unvisited vertices and the current vertex is a lower bound for the cost to finish the current path. It can be used with the A* algorithm as it can't overestimate the remaining distance (otherwise, the weight of the remaining path is smaller than the weight of minimum spanning tree and it spans the given vertices, which is a contradiction).

I've never tried it though so I don't know how well it'll work in practice.

Comment: But, can we create a minimum spanning tree with an asymmetric TSP?

Comment: @LuísPedroBorges It is a lower bound, anyway. The fact that the graph is directed can only increase the answer.

Answer (score 1):

There always are: `h(n) = 0` always works. It is useless, turning A* into Dijkstra, but it's definitely admissible.

An other obvious one: let `h(n)` be the shortest edge from the current city back to the beginning. Still a huge underestimation, but at least it's not necessarily zero. It's obviously valid, the loop has to be closed eventually and (given this partial route) there is no shorter way to do it.

You can be a bit more clever here, for example you could use linear programming (make two variables for each edge, one for each direction, then for every city make a constraint forcing the sum of entering edges to be 1 and a constraint forcing the sum of exiting edges to be one, weights are obviously the distances) to find an underestimation of the length from the current node back to the beginning while touching every city in the set of unvisited cities. Of course if you're doing that, you might as well drop A* and just use the usual integer linear programming tricks. A* doesn't seem like a good fit here (especially in the beginning, the branching factor is too high and the heuristics won't guide it enough yet), but I haven't tried this so who knows.

Also, given the solution from the LP, you can improve it a lot by using some simple tricks (and some advanced tricks that whole books have been written about, but let's not go there, read the books if you want to know). For example, one thing the LP likes to do is form lots of little triangles. This will satisfy the degree constraints everywhere locally and keeps everything nice and short. But it's not a tour, and forcing it be more like a tour will make the heuristic higher=better. To remove the sub-tours, you can detect them in the fractional solution and then force the number of entries to the subgraph to be at least 1 (it may have to become more than 1 at some point, so don't force it to be exactly 1) and force the number of exits to be at least 1, by adding the corresponding constraints and solving again. There are many more tricks, but this should already give a very reasonable heuristic, much closer to the actual cost than using any of the *over*estimating heuristics and dividing them by their worst case overestimation factor. The problem with those is that usually the heuristic is pretty good, much better than their worst case factor, and then dividing by the worst case factor really kills the quality of the heuristic.

Comment: Thanks for the tips!